# Combining Foursquare data with other applications

Tags: foursquare

Applications such as Foursquare and Groupon generally have a clause in their API Terms Of Reference which states that their data cannot be combined with that of others. I have been exploring Foursquare's API for some time now and am wondering how come sites like GTrot.com are able to display their results with records from both these websites (Foursquare and Groupon) and other similar sites?

Is it that Foursquare and Groupon are not really competitors and hence their data can be combined and displayed, whereas Foursquare and Google Places are competitors and so their data cannot be combined?

=====

For reference, here is a section from Foursquare's API Policy :-

***Venues Database Usage** 

We welcome you to use foursquare as your location database. You can associate additional content with our venue data in your system, but you may not combine our database with another database or export it on your own. Examples - 

* DO associate Wikipedia articles to foursquare venues and show them to users

* DON'T perform a search across both foursquare and Google Places, then return a combination of their results/data.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications can map between their existing database of locations and foursquare's in order to show foursquare information or offer foursquare-specific features (like checking in). This is fine under the foursquare ToS so long as the data is properly attributed to foursquare and the underlying database does not "learn" about new locations through the foursquare integration.

So for example you build a website that used Wikipedia locations but showed foursquare tips (properly attributed) about those locations. But you couldn't combine Wikipedia's set of locations with foursquare's set of locations to create a unified dataset.

Comment: Thanks @akdotcom. As I understand this is applicable only for location databases, not other things like events, deals, news, etc. So for example I can combine Foursquare locations with Yahoo news or Groupon deals or Tumblr blogs